# Installing Ubuntu-mate with dual boot option on Windows 10 - usb booting not happening

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 16.04, software-installation, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to dual-boot ubuntu mate with Windows 10. I created a Ubuntu Mate 16.04 USB by downloading the .iso image and then running the Universal USB software on a previously FAT32-formatted USB drive in Windows 10. I plugged the Live USB into CPU and then booted up the computer pressing F12 also. Once the boot menu opens, I choose Legacy option for the USB Storage device. Then a screen opens giving the usual options:

```
Try Ubuntu Mate without installing
Install, etc.
```

I choose first option. The monitor goes blank. CPU is still on but no display and i have to force shutdown by pressing the power button.

I need help with dual-booting.

It could have been that Windows 10 prevents booting from a USB because of the fast start-up option which i have already disabled. In fact, i have typed in "powercfg -h off" in the elevated command prompt. Also i checked that my Windows BIOS mode is indeed Legacy only so trying UEFI booting does not make sense and i have not given it a try.

Can it be that my method of preparing LiveUSB is at fault? Then can someone suggest other methods to do the same and indicate the best way? I have dual-booted the stock Ubuntu distro and Ubuntu mate in past on other computers and never had this issue.

What is bothering me is that the screen with options pops up and only when i do 'Try before installing', the monitor goes blank. I can try recreating a ubuntu usb and do the steps again.

**EDIT:**

I have tried almost every other way to dual-boot with windows 10 like trying software like rufus, startup disk creator, gparted, etc. I have even tried to partition the USB as NTFS which was not allowed. Can someone please tell me what can be the error? Every time the display just goes dark when i try to boot from the LiveUSB. This is occurring even with Ubuntu unity desktop and other versions of ubuntu like Kubuntu and lubuntu. After having exhausting all options that i could think of, i do not know what is the problem. Please let me know whatever information is needed about my system and i shall publish it here.

Comment: I'm quite sure its the USB method. In windows 10 i found Rufus more than usefull. I am booting same combination but with KDE version. Give it a try and let me know

Comment: Is windows 10 setup genuine

Comment: I tried USB booting it worked for me.

Comment: @HarshalBenake Win is genuine, yes. I have read that there is something called secure booting enabled by default which can mess up usb booting. But i think that applies for UEFI and i am just doing Legacy BIOS.

Comment: @fixxxera I will give Rufus a try and let you know.

Comment: So is it working now

Comment: No it's not still working.

Comment: Have you tried it with any software setup

Comment: See this, if nVidia you may need nomodeset. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  Or: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I have nvidia drivers!!! I have had very smooth experience with Windows 10 using nvidia but experience with nvidia on ubuntu has been terrible. I had to wipe out ubuntu once.

Comment: @oldfred So you are suggesting that pressing F6 and selecting nomodeset should do the job, right?

Comment: How did you install nVidia drivers? Best only from repository or ppa. And you must purge old nVidia driver if installing a new one. And must make sure version you install is correct one. Nomodeset is just until you do install the correct nVidia driver from System Settings, Software & Updates, drivers tab. But if incorrect one, you must purge & install correct. Only if very new nVidia card might you need ppa for very newest driver.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks a lot!!! It worked! It was a graphics drivers issue. I did not have any integrated graphics card but just the nvidia. So i used nomodeset option and once ubuntu mate was installed, it led me to automatically install the nvidia drivers and now i am having the best computing experience ever!!! If you add an answer, i will be very happy to check it as correct, the least i can do! Just a side-point for other readers, ubuntu unity does not assist users in automatically installing the correct nvidia drivers (which is not quite straightforward) like ubuntu mate does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows both BIOS & grub boot screens and adding nomodeset boot option. 
With UEFI & after install you have grub menu and have to manually add nomodeset in place of quiet splash.
At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

After install,if you boot to low quality graphics you can go into System Settings, Software & Updates, additional drivers tab and add the nVidia driver.

If you only get to a terminal or have to boot using recovery mode, make sure Internet is working and download correct driver.
Do not download .run driver directly from nVidia. If newest driver required because of a very new nVidia card/chip add ppa to get newest drives.

List drivers available, same list as system settings,  software updates,  additional drivers or last tab

```
ubuntu-drivers devices  
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

to install, if any nVidia driver previously installed you must purge old driver first:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If ppa required:
Shows standard repository versions

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

should show newest versions available in addition

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If older nVidia card, best to check which legacy nVidia driver is correct. Too new or too old of driver causes issues.

Legacy drivers by GPU model

http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html

Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version

http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Ppa Details on why and future incorporation to Ubuntu installer

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2015-August/004693.html

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa