# PC will not boot Ubuntu or boot USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb, ubuntu-gnome

I have a computer that refuses to boot due to problems with NVIDIA drivers. I have tried everything I can think of to fix the drivers, but it always boots into low-graphics mode.

Therefore, I decided to try and run boot-repair from a USB drive (Ubuntu GNOME) to see if that might fix it, and after I select "Try without installing" it hangs on a black screen forever. If I select "check disk for defects" it reboots the computer. The strange part is, if I insert the same USB into my laptop, it works perfectly. Secure boot is off, booting from USB is enabled in BIOs, I've tried multiple ports, different flash drives, resetting the BIOs to defaults, dialing back my overclock... Nothing works.

Here are my system specs:

Asrock z77 Pro3

i5 3570k

32GB DDR3

PNY GTX 1060 6GB

256GB lite-on ssd

Comment: P.S. I think your problem with he Nvidia drivers can be fixed by adding `nomodeset`.

Comment: Nope, that's already been done. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Some just connect to motherboard Intel video to install system. Then install ppa and nVidia driver. You need ppa to get the vary newest nVidia driver. If you installed any other nVidia driver, you must purge first. http://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413 and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: @oldfred Thanks, I'll try uninstalling the card to boot the USB drive. I have already purged the old nvidia drivers, added the ppa, and installed the new drivers though.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You probably need 16.04 to have it work with the very newest nVidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hardware (video card and ram) are seated correctly in your motherboard. If you can, create a second live USB, perhaps with a different version of Linux and see if you can boot from that.

Comment: My computer can boot Windows and run games perfectly, so I don't think that will work. Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 0):

and check if power cable is plugged. there are nouveau , "nvidia legacy" and nvidia drivers. You can blacklist each in `/etc/modeprobe.d/whatsoever.conf` 
by add `blacklist nouveau` or so.