# Low Resolution on 16.04 with EVGA GTX960

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

**The Setup**

Dual boot machine (Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04) with EVGA GTX960 gpu. Monitor is an Asus V247H-P capable of 1920x1080, connected via DVI (also tried with HDMI, made no difference).

**Install**

In order to install Ubuntu I had to add `nomodeset` to avoid a black screen - ok, makes sense, I didn't have Nvidia drivers at that point.

**The Problem**

Install went smoothly (not my first rodeo) but gave a max resolution of 640x480. I used software update to switch to proprietary Nvidia drivers (369, I believe, I'm not at my pc). After reboot, my max resolution is 1360x768. Better, but not 1080p.

Nvidia drivers appear to be loading properly, according to `Xorg.0.log`.

**1st Attempt**

Ran `sudo nvidia-xconfig` to create an `xorg.conf` file, then rebooted. Now resolution is back down to 640x480 max!

If I delete `xorg.conf` it allows 1360x768 again.

**2nd Attempt**

Added the following lines to `xorg.conf`, in the appropriate places, as per suggestions found online (I'm going by memory here):

```
Option "ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck"
Modeline... [from running gtf]
Modes... [modeline name from gtf]
HorizSync 30.0 - 80.0
VertRefresh 56.0 - 76.0
```

and a couple other things. I can edit tomorrow to include the exact lines, if necessary. The exact numbers I used for `HorizSync` and `VertRefresh` might be off here.

This allowed a resolution of 1920x1080 however there was "twinkling" all over the screen. I'm not sure how else to describe it.

**Next Steps?**

At this point I'm not sure what to do. I can't find evidence of anyone else having similar issues with this setup.

Comment: I had similar issues and used this [guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics). Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Had similar issues with my gtx 1060 and I used [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413). If the one MIchael suggested didn't help, maybe look at this one. This was quite a fight.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot (or short video) of the "twinkling" would help us help you! I'm sure the exact version of drivers that you are using as well as the true content of xorg.conf could be useful. As is I'm unclear as to what you are asking and not entirely convinced that this question isn't a duplicate of [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: Could you add the complete `xorg.conf` to the question.