# Ubuntu 17.10 - Nvidea 1050 drivers can't install, crappy video performance.. :(

Tags: drivers, video, 17.10

VLC doesn't show any video data at all, just plays audio.
The default media player on my NVidea 1050 card for which i downloaded the correct drivers won't install because the lightdm / gdm / whatever is still running..

i'd appreciate a quick and concise tip on how to disable the lightdm / gdm / whatever subsystem (aka the desktop manager and window manager etc etc), so that i can install the right nvidea drivers to see if that fixes the problem of having a 4K 2000-bucks+ system that can't even play a 1080p movie correctly.

many sincere thanks in advance for any help you can offer me without pointing me in the wrong direction or the direction of what *may* be a solution.

Comment: **NVIDIA** drivers can and should be installed at the Additional Drivers.

Comment: And if you have installed one driver, you must totally purge before installing another. Otherwise major conflicts. Even worse conflicts if you install the .run version directly from nVidia. Your card is so new, you probably need ppa to get newest pre-configured for Ubuntu nVidia driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers & https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: thanks guys.. 

here's my current thinking :
microsoft.com : i'll get my dad to get me a DVD-RW disc to write that win10_1709_*.iso 64 bit version so i can re-install windows. :)
i'm really eager to play far-cry 5, black ops 3, and of course my favorite of today's gaming options : battle field 4 :)

and notepad-plus-plus is pretty darn good too.

ubuntu.com : i'll get the dual-boot setup that you offer to work. i have the diskspace, time, and mental and emo energy to make it happen, and i already have the right 17.10 distribution on an USB keychain drive. :)

Comment: ubuntu.com : i'm very happy the default video player is performing better after my report on askubuntu.com :)
it's not perfect yet, quick action scenes in hollywood movies are still jerky, but it'll do. the important thing is prioritizing audio output over video output, for me at least.