# Is it possible to install grub in two locations?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I haphazardly confirmed some grub-related prompt and I suspect it as the culprit to my being unable to boot.

I've tried boot repair multiple times but am still unable to get my Ubuntu install working again. It had been working fine for months before it stopped.

Here's the boot-repair dump. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FSp7JB72Px/

Comment: Did you add a drive? Or unplug a drive? It originally showed an ESP on sdb and only the FAT32 partition. Boot-Repair reinstalled to sda. But you have two Windows entries, one for Ubuntu/grub's shimx64.efi and one for Windows. Have you turned off Windows fast start up? It shows hibernated, which causes issues.  From UEFI menu does hard drive boot work? What errors are you now getting?  Whjat brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: I didn't add or remove any drives, though I did reformat one in vain. Windows fast start up is disabled.

It's a custom build with an intel chip and nvidia 1080.  

I only get errors sometimes now and it says `invalid video mode specification 'text' . Booting in blind mode`

Comment: It looks like this question  is pointing to a similar issue, though still unresolved: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012527/two-grub-menus-overriding

Comment: Script usually shows what video driver. Did you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository and use ppa to get newest driver? Do not install .run file directly from nVidia. And if changing drivers, you must totally purge or else conflicts & issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: Everything was working fine until recently, and I hadn't messed with any drivers. Check out how glitchy grub is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp9231cGAks

Comment: see also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocKXhyOh2Qg

Comment: May be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1752767

Comment: That seems to be it :'(