# Two grub menus overriding

Tags: boot, grub2, menu, grub-legacy

i started having these 2 overriding grub menus all of a sudden

the purple one works .. while as the black one is just like an image

[Image showing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvCgj.jpg)

Comment: Is it this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1752767

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting nearly the same thing. I have a pc with Windows and Ubuntu on two different drives and grub2 was working fine. After a normal Ubuntu updating a couple of days ago,in which grub2 got updated, grub2 freezes and displays a black grub2 screen over the purple one. Tried doing boot-repair after booting with and Ubuntu USB but boot-repair didn't solve it.

Comment: yeah this happened to me after the last grub update too ..