# Booting from SSD on EP2C602-4L/D16

Tags: boot, ssd

I've been running Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier on this motherboard with an HDD for a year and took an SSD from another working PC and tried to do a fresh install from a live USB. The install went fine but when I try to boot from the SSD I get a line of scrambled colors across the screen like this | | | |.

The SSD is recognized in BIOS and I can see it and move files in the live USB. I'm using the same SATAIII port and cable I used for the HDD. I've updated BIOS to P1.90 the latest version. SATA mode is set to ACHI. I can't really think of anything else to try. I've read other threads of people using SSDs with these boards.

Comment: Did you also update firmware on SSD? But video issues are normally related to video driver. What video card/chip and have you installed same driver as you have/had with HDD?

Comment: Haven't tried updating firmware for the SSD I'll look into that. I don't think it's a video issue since the live USB works fine and I can put the same OS on the HDD and it works fine. I'm using a GTX1050Ti. I could try moving it to onboard video though. I'm not able to get it to boot once I've done the install from the live USB so I'm just using stock drivers as part of the install.

Comment: Booted using the on board VGA and it worked fine. Thanks for the help! Probably wouldn't have tried troubleshooting video otherwise lol.

Comment: With nVidia card, you normally need nomodeset to boot installer and first boot or until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository or add in ppa. Recovery mode also has nomodeset as default boot parameter.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booted using the on board VGA and it worked fine. Thanks for the help! Probably wouldn't have tried troubleshooting video otherwise lol.