# dual boot Ubuntu-Windows crash and grub prompt

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10, 18.10

I am trying to dual boot a computer with pre-installed Windows10. My goal is to install the latest version of Ubuntu18 in a partition.
I have followed the instructions I found. I

- unflagged "turn on fast startup"
- unflagged "secure boot"
- created an installation USB key
- freed some space from Windows disk management
- rebooted and selected the option "Install Ubuntu"

everything went on smoothly until the end of the installation. Then I was asked to reboot but, as soon as I clicked that option, the computer became unresponsive. I may have done a terrible mistake here because after some (long) time I decided to switch off and back on.

Next, grub prompt appeared and it was impossible to enter either ubuntu or Windows

After some unsuccesful attempts, I just used F11 and managed to go back to Windows (which works just fine)

Now the system seems to ignore the partition or grub if I reboot. my questions

- did I mess everything up when the system seemed unresponsive or something had already gone wrong?
- since the installation seemed to be succesfully completed, is there a chance to get the grub prompt back and fix things from there?
- I am quite tempted to just delete the "broken" partition from Windows and repeat the passages, but I may solve nothing and make thing worse... or maybe not?

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

edit: by reboot+F11+ubuntu disk I can get back to the grub prompt.
then if I type

```
ls (hd0,1)/efi/ubuntu/
```

I get

```
./ ../ grubx64.efi shimx64.efi mmx64.efi bootx64.csv grub.cfg
```

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hp pavilion gaming laptop 15, nvidia geforce gtx 1050 ti. for ppa version shouldn't I be able to enter ubuntu?

Comment: You add Boot-Repair to Ubuntu live installer and run it in live mode, not install mode. Did you not need nomodeset to boot live installer? Normally with nVidia you need nomodeset boot parameter both to install & first boot or until you install nVidia driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap

Comment: Thank you but I cannot access live mode (which should be "try ubuntu" if I am not mistaken). Everything seemed fine without nomodeset...

Comment: Did your live installer get corrupted during install?  You need to get that to work.

Comment: the live installer seems to be fine...

Comment: Then add Boot-Repair to live installer and run report. Post link it gives to pastebin site above in first post. Do not run any fixes until someone reviews report. have you run all the updates, or confirmed you have latest versions of UEFI & SSD firmware? And changed drive to AHCI?