# How to make nvidia drivers work without having the boot problem of clean, n/n files, n/n blocks

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

**What I need**

I need to use tensorflow and train my networks with the GPU.
I [installed](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc) tensorflow gpu using anaconda on a new env using `conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu`. That should correctly install CUDA. However, although Tensorflow was correctly using CUDA, it cannot see the GPU:

```
assert tf.test.is_built_with_cuda() # True
assert tf.test.is_gpu_available()   # False
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 8659538338150116047
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 3957650727733291855
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

Another thing is that in ¨display¨ the screen appears as ¨unknown device¨ and my max resolution is 1024x768.

---

**What I do**

My drivers for NVIDIA the generic X.Org, so I try to install nvidia's proprietary drivers. I open the following image:

[image]

So I select the button for using nvidia-driver-430.

The problem is that after re-booting I end up with the problem described here: [clean, n/n files, n/n blocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

I correctly fix this by running `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` on recovery mode. However, I end up with the drivers not being installed again.
Running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` gets the problem again.

*How can I install them without a problem?*

---

**Hardware and OS**

So I have my new PC for work on which I will run tensorflow networks for GPU. 
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with a Nvidia MSI GeForce RTX 2080 TI GAMING X TRIO

---

**Debugging**

If I try `ubuntu-drivers devices` I get:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E07sv00001462sd00003715bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

However, according to [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) I should also be getting the `model` (geforce 2080 rtx ti) but I don´t.

---

I installed windows to see if it was a problem with Ubuntu. However in windows is also not working properly. I have the following on "Device Manager":

[image]

I went to the [official Windows support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4341212/windows-10-fix-graphics-device-problems-error-code-43) and do the following:
If I try to update driver it says the correct driver is already installed. If I try to uninstall and then "scan for hardware changes" the OS crashes and reboots.

---

I found a Nvidia NVS 315 in my office so I plugged it to see if it worked. I booted in windows and it's now working as charm.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: How do I do that? Isn't that supposed to be a Windows thing? I guessed it was from the BIOS. I changed the option `Windows 8/10 Features` to `Òther OS`. However it didn't worked. Stucked again as usual. I have GIGABYTE Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI motherboard.

Comment: Yes, it is in BIOS, boot section.

Comment: Ok, so I just found that as my "CSM Support" was enabled, that means automatically that Secure Boot is disabled. Any other ideas?

Comment: But then did you install in UEFI boot mode? Should work whether UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy, but most work now is done on UEFI systems. Did you totally purge old nVidia driver before installing a new one? Otherwise conflicts. Did you add ppa to get newest nVidia driver? https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: I run the command `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to be able to boot again so I believe I have. I believe my boot mode is UEFI. I didn´t add the ppa because I did it from the GUI. You think I should try to install them via de command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was either a driver/OS problem or hardware.

For that I tried it on Windows. As the board didn't work on windows I concluded it was a hardware problem.

Now it can be either the motherboard or the GPU, so I tried another Nvidia GPU and worked so the most likely **conclusion is that my GPU (GeForce 2080) was faulty**.