# Locked on boot with fresh install complete successfully and after install of nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

First of all thanks in advance for trying to help me.

I'll try to be exhaustive.

**What I want to do:**

Simply install and use ubuntu 20.04.

**Issue:**

After successfully installed Ubuntu without external drivers, I update ubuntu, and reboot with success.

Then I try to install NVidia drivers for use my GPU with my 3 screens.
Trying to install with :

- option in install workflow (on install process, not after).
- command line, several tries :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460 || sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
sudo reboot
```

- update GUI

All seems to work, so I reboot.

But on next boot, I get the screen with option to bios access (enter del to...), I do nothing and let the boot sequence, boot on ubuntu BUT.

Nothing to do, I remain locked on a screen who look like boot screen, ROG logo and wait for ubuntu logo and loader appear, but he don't.

And can't do anything, trying all ctrl + alt + F*, ctrl + x.

Nothing work, I stay here as long I don't reboot manually.

**Config:**

Motherboard: X570E Asus ROG
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
GPU: Aorus 3060ti Master
SSD: M2 970evo plus

Thanks for reading,

Thomas

Comment: You can only install one driver. If installing a different driver, you must purge old driver first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap  If you just do autoinstall, it should now install the most current version for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a comment but I seem to be unable to.

Are you able to see the GRUB Recovery Menu? It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqSok.png
If not you could try pressing "ESC" at boot time and it should show. Select an option and on the top left let us know what you see and if you get past the following or if you get stuck:

```
Loading Linux 5.11.0-17-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

If you get stuck there, access the grub menu again, highlight the main option and press "E" to edit it.

Navigate down to the line beginning "linux ..." and add `nomodeset` at the end of the line. Then, below the last "initrd /initrd.img..." line add:

- `echo 'Loaded Linux kernel...'`
- `sleep 5`

Reboot and let us know of any changes.