# Clevo laptop with 12th gen Intel cpu and nvidia rtx 3060 - nvidia GPU stopped working suddenly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 22.04

Editing this question in the hope that someone could find it useful.

After automatically updating drivers and kernel on Ubuntu 22.04 the laptop GPU stopped working. There was no apparent reason and the problem happened suddenly, after rebooting from suspend.

Symptoms to look out for -

- The laptop would boot to a black screen or a black screen with a thin line at the bottom of the screen, showing the colour of the background.
- Boot log would show something like this. *“Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.”*

Attempted fixes - (*the same problem, as mentioned above, persisted after every fix*)

- Reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04/18.04
- Not updating the kernel/updating the kernel
- Using Ubuntu “software and updates” selecting the gpu driver.
- Nvidia drivers tested 470, 490, 515 (open and proprietary) and 525 (open kernel and proprietary)
- Building Nvidia drivers from source.

Solution -

- Laptop was returned to the seller and they confirmed that it was a faulty GPU.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to solve.  Did you ever get to the latest 5.15.0-56 kernel with a working Nvidia 525 driver?   After that point, you tried to update the kernel to a 6.0... but not sure that would qualify as a standard flavor of Ubuntu qualifying for this site.

Comment: You must purge old driver before installing new driver. And should only install from Ubuntu repository, otherwise kernel changes do not get driver added back in. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers You now do not need ppa, but must purge if changing driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap

Comment: @ubfan1 yes. I initially never wanted to upgrade the kernel, it happened because I had the install by the company I bought the laptop from. After fresh install I tried with the non updated kernel, didn’t work. Then I completely updated ubuntu and tried all the methods suggested. But the same error occurs, regardless of kernel. I tried the latest nvidia driver yes. I’ve installed ubuntu fresh, maybe 10 times, to make sure my constant failures and purging of drivers wasn’t breaking anything.

Comment: @oldfred hey, I always purge remove nvidia drivers and always use autoremove to make sure there isn’t a trace left of any nvidia dependencies. I’ve also reinstalled Ubuntu fresh multiple times to make sure purging of drivers too many times doesn’t cause other issues. I’ve tried with the standard nvidia drivers and adding the ppa drivers, no difference.

Comment: If your system vendor updated Ubuntu to a non-standard Ubuntu kernel are they modifying kernel and maybe other drivers for their system? Do they have their own pp, adding future version sources,  or how would you have gotten a newer kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop's GPU was actually faulty and it was not a software issue.