# Having issues installing a GeForce RTX 3060 with Ubuntu

Tags: gpu, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

I've been trying to get a GeForce RTX 3060 up and running on my PC, but I'm having issues getting it installed with the drivers. I used the following code:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

But upon checking if the installation worked using nvidia-settings I got the error messages:

```
$ nvidia-settings
ERROR: A query to find an object was unsuccessful
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:7623): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:01:58.892: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 16:01:58.894: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 16:01:58.894: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

It looks like the installation was unsuccessful. Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this? I've tried doing a clean uninstall and use alternative installation methods, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought command was `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` And to see if installed. `dkms status` Which will show its now part of kernel drivers. But if you previously installed a nVidia driver, you have to purge first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap

Comment: Also, don't forget to reboot after changing graphics drivers.