# How do I install an arbitrary proprietary NVidia GPU driver on Ubuntu Studio 22.04?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, ubuntu-studio

I am trying to roll back my currently installed proprietary NVidia driver (v535) to an older version because I suspect the latest update causes problems with many Windows games played through Proton on Steam.

The driver manager in KDE does not seem to allow me to select another driver like I could in previous releases of Ubuntu Studio - the button to "Apply changes" is greyed out:

[image]

All the questions I find here either relate to installing the latest driver, repairing a broken install, or are simply outdated.

What is the correct procedure to follow to safely install an **arbitrary Nvidia driver version** on Ubuntu Studio 22.04?

Comment: It makes zero scense to talk about installing an arbitrary package xxx safely. All packages allowed in the repositories are tested one way or another, so they can't be arbitrary. Installing an arbitrary package is inherently unsafe, and should be avoided.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers list --gpgpu` is the recommended method nowadays to view available. see its help on how to install.

Comment: When I say "arbitrary" I mean any version available in the repositories, not only the latest one. As you see in the screenshot, multiple versions are available. All of these should be safe and tested. The obvious way to select them in the Driver Manager and reboot, which already does not work anymore apparently, is not.

Comment: @rinzwind Thank you. Does that mean doing it using `ubuntu-drivers install`, without reverting to nouveau, rebooting and re-installing another driver is safe today and won't mess up my system? Side question - why does `ubuntu-drivers list --gpgpu` not list the version I had installed (530) before the update to 535?

Comment: Best to always purge old driver before installing new one. Typically new driver does not uninstall old, may only overwrite part of it & then you get conflicts. Older instructions that added ppa, not now required, otherwise the same: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383560&p=13735336#post13735336

Comment: Thank you @oldfred - this worked well. Would you mind posting it as an answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to always purge old driver before installing new one. Typically new driver does not uninstall old, may only overwrite part of it & then you get conflicts.
Always install nVidia drivers from Ubuntu repository. The nVidia .run file directly from nVidia is not updated to work easily with Ubuntu. You in effect have to reinstall with every kernel update with dkms. Repository has latest nVidia driver so no need to directly download it, anyway. And Ubuntu repository version is automatically updated into every new kernel.

You can see what is installed with these:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
dkms status
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

This should show available versions, but best to install recommended.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If you just want default version - recommended one

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Or you can manually choose any in list.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-XXX
```

If you have installed a previous version you must purge. And if installed older bumblebee, purge that also as not used now.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee primus bbswitch-dkms
```

[Installing Ubuntu-mate with dual boot option on Windows 10 - usb booting not happening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413)