# Problem with installation ubuntu on my xps 9510

Tags: system-installation, dell, xps

Hello i have Dell XPS 15 9510 and i want to install ubunty 23.04 or 22.10 but i cannot i have problems with drivers of nvidia and problem with xfs files encrypted. Can someone tell me how to install ubuntu on my laptopo without any problems? Is it possible ?

Comment: There isn’t enough information here to help you; have a look at the Ubuntu help pages to get started, and Dell have a very basic guide at https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc  I’d recommend installing 22.04LTS, not 23.04 or 22.10 - it’ll save you having to upgrade soon.

Comment: But i have already try to install 22.04 LTS and i still have problems with ACPI and Nvidia drivers. System works only on X.org drivers. When i want to update system crushed and stay freezed on pointer in left upper corner

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode to terminal? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22 If wrong version installed be sure to run purge command first. Best to choose to install proprietary drivers as part of install and then nVidia driver installed.