# Windows 11 dualboot ubuntu 22.04, casually crashing or back to login screen in linux

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, crash, login-screen, windows-11

The problem is pretty much in the title, windows work perfectly, I deactivated the fast start beacuse I read can cause problems. I have windows in a ssd, ubuntu in a usb and shared hdd with windows.
There is somenthing I could do to prevent crash and push to login screen? It happens the two things togheter, but one at time too so I think this are two different issues.
Thank you for help

Comment: What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware to latest available? What video card/chip? Can you boot live installer? Did you select install optional restricted drivers when installing to get correct video or other driver for your system?

Comment: Medion 64bit, i7-9700, Nvidia GeForce rtx 2060 I don't know about UEFI & SSD firmware. I tried to install nvidia 535 but was not working properly so I return back to X.Org X server one

Comment: and I check proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)

Comment: UEFI and SSD are the last avaible sorry to take much time to check, but I am still a newbie. Ty for your help @oldfred

Comment: If you can boot recovery mode you can install the nVidia driver, if you enable networking & in terminal install driver.`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` If wrong driver installed, you must purge first or conflicts will cause problems. Or Drivers tab in Software. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22