Unable to install NVIDIA drivers with apt-get
I am trying to install the recommended NVIDIA driver by the following command:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-550

But I keep getting the following error message:
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-cfg1-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [145 kB]
Err:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-cfg1-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-cfg1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-common-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [17.1 kB]
Err:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-common-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-common-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-decode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [2,129 kB]
Err:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-decode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-decode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-decode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [1,783 kB]
Err:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-decode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-decode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-encode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [100 kB]
Err:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-encode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-encode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-encode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [107 kB]
Err:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-encode-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-encode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-extra-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [71.1 kB]
Err:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-extra-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-extra-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:8 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-fbc1-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [59.7 kB]
Err:8 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-fbc1-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:9 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-fbc1-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [54.9 kB]
Err:9 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-fbc1-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:10 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-gl-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [136 MB]
Err:10 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-gl-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:11 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-gl-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [17.8 MB]
Err:11 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libnvidia-gl-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:12 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libxnvctrl0 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [21.3 kB]
Err:12 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  libxnvctrl0 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libxnvctrl0_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:13 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-compute-utils-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [118 kB]
Err:13 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-compute-utils-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:14 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-kernel-source-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [41.1 MB]
Err:14 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-kernel-source-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-kernel-source-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:15 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.15 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [36.8 MB]
Err:15 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.15 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.15_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:16 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-kernel-common-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [109 kB]
Err:16 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-kernel-common-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-kernel-common-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:17 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-dkms-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [36.2 kB]
Err:17 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-dkms-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-dkms-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:18 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-utils-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [494 kB]
Err:18 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-utils-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-utils-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:19 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [1,534 kB]
Err:19 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:20 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-driver-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [489 kB]
Err:20 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-driver-550 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-driver-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
Get:21 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-settings 550.54.15-0ubuntu1 [947 kB]
Err:21 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  nvidia-settings 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-settings_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-cfg1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-cfg1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-common-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_all.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-common-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-decode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-decode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-decode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-decode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-encode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-encode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-encode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-encode-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-extra-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-extra-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-fbc1-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libxnvctrl0_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libxnvctrl0_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-kernel-source-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-kernel-source-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.15_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.15_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-kernel-common-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-kernel-common-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-dkms-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-dkms-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-utils-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-utils-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-driver-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-driver-550_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-settings_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./nvidia-settings_550.54.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Could someone help me out with this? I need the NVIDIA-driver and CUDA toolkit for tensorflow.

use ubuntu-drivers it is a guided install of all available 3rd party drivers. You only posted parts of the message. as it states "not found" i would assume version 550 is lacking on that server. ubuntu-drivers will pick the version itself.

How do I use ubuntu-drivers exactly?

type it as that in command line and the help will show

If you have any nVidia installed best to purge. A new driver install can create conflicts with a previous install of a different version. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22

I get the same error using ubuntu-drivers. Moreover, I do have some files related to NVIDIA drivers already on my system but when I try to remove them I simply get a file not found error.

Potential Reason
It seems like there are dependency issues with the nvidia-driver-550 (at least on Ubuntu 22.04), which directly depends on i.a.:

linux-modules-nvidia-550-oem-22.04d
nvidia-kernel-common-550 (<= 550.54.15-1) as well as nvidia-kernel-common-550 (>= 550.54.15)
nvidia-kernel-source-550 (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu1) and some more that require version 550.54.15-0ubuntu1

Digging one layer down in the hierarchy, we find that
linux-modules-nvidia-550-oem-22.04d itself, however, depends on nvidia-kernel-common-550 (>= 550.67).
This results in installing the precompiled kernel version 550.54.15-0ubuntu1, but parts of the driver require the newer kernel version 550.67, resulting in conflicts.
Temporary Work-Around
For me (on my Laptop) worked the following solution:

I purged all Nvidia packages:

sudo apt purge *nvidia*


reboot

installed the recommended server version with


sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu

The server versions are recommended for a more extended period than the regular versions, so the above automatically installed the nvidia-kernel-535-server.
Note Regarding Compatability of Nvidia Kernel <-> CUDA <-> TensorFlow
The versions of the three must be compatible.
Tensorflow supports currently the following CUDA versions: Tensorflow GPU Support Matrix.
The current compatibility of CUDA and Nvidia Drivers can be found here.
Nvidia provides on this page more background information on why CUDA and Nvidia Kernel versions must be compatible and how to resolve issues.
