Unable to load into ubuntu in dual boot
I have recently got a dell XPS 8960 desktop, I have partitioned off the SSD in this and set up dual boot alongside windows boot manager as i have successfully done in the past on different machines.
However whenever I go to boot into ubuntu this just shows a black screen with a flashing underscore in the top right, If I boot into ubuntu in safe mode this loads up fine but just can't boot normally. Any though or help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Does this answer your question? Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot

if you need Safe Boot, then you probably have nVidia and need to install nVidia drivers. Best during install to select to include the optional restricted drivers. But if you can boot to grub recovery mode and boot, you can install the driver from the terminal mode. Turn on Internet & add driver. Purge if wrong driver installed.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413


first Update Grub Configuration
boot into ubuntu in safe mode
in terminal run "sudo update-grub"

Check UEFI/Secure Boot Settings
Disable secure boot in Bios
check Fast Boot that should be disabled

Update Ubuntu
Boot into Safe mode
on terminal run the commands in sudo
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade

Check Logs for Errors
Boot up the PC in Safe mode and check the log file by following command and share it here, so we can chack it together
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i error
let me know if it solved the issue


