Nvidia graphics driver only works in one kernel?
I currently see that I have two Linux kernels installed (5.15.0-105-generic and 5.15.0-102-generic). Due to issues with sleep mode, I was testing the 5.15.0-102-generic kernel, and I noticed that the Nvidia graphics driver does not work there. However, it works in 5.15.0-105-generic.
How can that be? Does the Nvidia driver only works together with the most recent Linux kernel on my system?
Maybe I need to reinstall (or reconfigure?) the Nvidia driver for the older kernel? How?
Can I have multiple Nvidia graphics drivers installed at the same time? (Just like I have multiple Linux kernels installed at the same time.)
Edit I now manually did sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-545-5.15.0-102-generic. That seems to have solved it. But was that correct? Will apt autoremove still remove this automatically correctly when I don't need it anymore? If not, how can I change it?

If you install a different nVidia driver you must purge old first or you get conflicts. But if installed from Ubuntu repository it should automatically add to new kernels. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

@oldfred All drivers were always installed via apt. So what you are saying is, I must never have multiple Nvidia drivers installed at the same time? I can only have one single driver installed? I.e. that effecitivly means, I can also never have multiple Linux kernels installed (and in a working state) at the same time? But actually it seems to work just fine what I did, so what you say is wrong?

No, the one driver should be installed into each kernel when kernel is installed. What is installed
dkms status  You may have needed this sudo update-initramfs -u -k to include kernel & add drivers.

What is the difference between linux-modules-nvidia-5.15.0-102-generic and linux-modules-nvidia-5.15.0-105-generic? So you say, just installing those packages is not enough, I also need to use update-initramfs? But this seems wrong, because actually it seems to be enough to just install those? At least it works for me?

It then looks like you have two different but similar packages. And that may be why it is not updating. Only one version should be installed. and then all updates should work automatically.

What do you mean, what is not updating? You say, when I install linux-image-5.15.0-102-generic, then apt should be clever enough to automatically install linux-modules-nvidia-545-5.15.0-102-generic as well? Are you sure? But this sounds like an apt issue then?

Apt does not install another nVidia, dkms runs and adds the nVidia driver into new kernel. Bu tif you have two drivers or installed directly from nVidia then dkms does not add driver automatically.

As said, everything I have installed is via apt. I never said that I installed anything directly from nvidia. I'm not really sure I understand what you mean. For my case, i.e. all via apt, after apt install linux-image-5.15.0-102-generic, what is the recommended way to get Nvidia drivers? Just apt install linux-modules-nvidia-545-5.15.0-102-generic? Or dkms instead and not using apt? What is the problem with apt?

It sounds like you are doing what is correct from what I know. So must be some other issue that I do not understand. Did you (or Window) change to turn UEFI Secure Boot on, so then you have to create a MOK key for any proprietary drivers?

What issue do you mean? I don't really have any issue. I just had a few questions here. Everything works fine for me.
