Unable to access Ubuntu partition after setting up multiboot
Recently I have been setting up a multiboot system with two Linux versions and Windows. The steps I have taken are as follows.

Installed Ubuntu Studio and have been using it for a few years now as my only OS.

Added Debian as a second OS on the same hard drive. Updated Grub and everything was working fine.

Pulled out the hard drive and installed Windows on the second drive. It booted without issue.

Reinstalled the first drive and set the BIOS boot to it first.

Ran sudo update grub to add Windows, and I am able to boot into Windows as well as Debian, but I am unable to boot into Ubuntu Studio. While booting it gives me the following errors then goes to a login screen.


[   4.895533] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   4.895657] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[   4.895659] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed- -110 
[FAILED] Failed to start snap.cups.cups-browsed.service - Service for snap application cups.cups-browsed.
[FAILED} Failed to start snap.cups.cupsd.service - service for snap application ccups.cupsd. 

The login shows the correct user name, but does nothing when the password is entered.
Is there any way to recover this OS, or at the very least access the files on that partition?.

Grub only boots working Windows or no fast startup, hibernation nor chkdsk. Since Debian last install,  expect its grub to be default. Did you boot both installs before removing drive? Often when removing a drive the UEFI entry reverts to some non-working default. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bVbHmzHkJQ/

Sorry for the multiple comments didn't realize hitting enter sends the comment.Thanks, for the Response.   Yes both versions of Linux booted up ok before pulling the drive and installing Windows on the second drive.  Now the second version of Linux boots as well as Windows.  I assume because Grub was installed when I installed the second version of Linux.

Looks ok except line 158. You may have boot,esp flags on  nvme1n1p2. Use gparted and remove those flags. the run sudo update-grub. if you want Ubuntu as default, boot into Ubuntu install from either UEFI one time boot menu or Debian and run sudo grub-install and then you may need a grub update to add Debian to Ubuntu grub menu.

Thanks for the response.  I did as you suggested and removed the flag then ran update-grub.   Grub finds both Windows and Ubuntu but still unable to log into Ubuntu.  Ubuntu did do an unattended update when I tried to shut down the computer.  But still unable to log in.

So Debian & Windows work? Can you boot Ubuntu recovery mode? Or second line in grub menu.

yes I'm able to boot into recovery mode.   I created a new user with the hopes it would allow me to login but it still does not.

Then graphics issue and you show a nVidia error of some sort. How did you install nVidia driver? From Ubuntu repository or .run file from nVidia. The .run file requires effort with every kernel update, so only use driver from Ubuntu repository. At recovery mode, you can purge & reinstall correct nVidia driver. If .run you have to use it to uninstall. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22

Honestly I can't remember how I installed the video drivers.  It would have been done way before I did the windows installation.   I will see about purging and reinstalling the drivers.   Thanks
