Ubuntu 24.04 unusable laggy and slow
I have a dell inspiration 16 plus 7620 with a NVIDIA RTX 3050 4GB and 16GB RAM.
Before installing Ubuntu 24.04 I had 23.04 which was working perfectly fine.
Now I wanted to install 24.04 and even in the installing process my mouse and keyboard input were really slow and it almost impossible to click or type stuff. I remember I had this issue also during the installation process of 23.04 but I forgot what I changed, because it was running perfectly after the change.
I think it has something to do with graphics, because in safe graphic mode it works perfectly (during boot from USB).
Things I’ve already done:

installed recommended driver 535
tried to change the grub default file “quiet splash”
wayland enable =false
rebooted couple times
Apt update and upgrade

Nothing works, and I’m searching for hours and can’t find the right answer on the internet. I’m not an Ubuntu expert so I would appreciate any help!
Edit: When I move the mouse to the top of the screen I can see the tip of it moving correctly but the rest of it moves laggy. It looks like there is a “second” screen which is lagging and behind it there is the “correct” screen.

I think this is not a version problem since I had the same issue in the previous version. I think it is a graphics issue

Did you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository when installing. Check box on restricted extra drivers? You can see if installed. What is installed
dkms status  If wrong nVidia driver or upgrade, you must purge & install correct driver
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

@oldfred dkms status is empty since there was no Nvidia kernel installed from dkms. I just have the proprietary 535

@720Degrees What method did you use to install the 535 driver?

@720Degrees Also, if you're logged in using Wayland, then log out and log back in using Xorg or X11 instead of Wayland because Nvidia is known to not work well with Wayland.

@mchid I only logged in as Ubuntu or xorg. Also the lagg already starts at the login page. Right now I installed it with the following command sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-dkms535 . dkms status gives me: „nvidia/535.183.01, 6.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed“

Does sudo ubuntu-drivers say this is the recommended driver?

Sorry sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

If it says the correct recommended driver is the one you're using, then check your display settings, try a different resolution. Also run sudo journalctl -b | grep -i error to see if there's anything in the logs that points to the source of the issue.

@mchid it says distro non-free recommended. sudo journalctl -b | grep -i error  shows a lot of errors actually. Some of them are laptop kernel, snapd, gdm-x-session, etc. should I print them in here?

@720Degrees Yes, more information is always good. x-session stuff is probably relevant, although no need to post the repeats of the initial error, probably just post one of each error that shows up

@720Degrees Nevermind. I see you've found a solution.

So after hours of research I finally found the solution to my problem. It is also answered here:
Built-in laptop screen is laggy even when external monitor is not a problem
I changed in /etc/default/grub the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= quiet splash to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= quiet splash i915.tuxedo_disable_psr2=1 i915.enable_psr=0 as described in the link above. I just quite did not get the explanation since I am very new to this topic, so I would be very happy if someone could break it down, why this small change worked for me.
