# Black screen on grub menu and uefi, like the nvidia drivers load with the system, not before? And games stopped to run

Tags: grub2, nvidia, uefi, steam

Long story short, I had a working Ubuntu 23.04 but then power surge happened, my uefi settings (bios) were probably reset and I lost video output on DP. I've fixed it I thought, but as most of the bios changes were educated guesses and now I have some problems with other things (Steam game I was playing went from random freezes to not running at all) I wanted to revise the changes I've made, before that I've reinstalled nvidia drivers with `ubuntu-drivers`, but now I can't enter bios anymore: I can't see grub menu, it's there and it can be interacted with, I just have black screen on top of it... and even if I go all the way to the bottom in the dark, to the firmware settings option, I can't see anything... clicking F2 or Delete won't show me anything either... it's like the GPU starts working after Ubuntu actually boots, and it's true for both open-source and propetiary nvidia drivers. And now none of my Steam games run at all... I believe it's all connected, but I have no idea what to do... these are messages when the games fail to run, maybe that will be important to figure it out:

```
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=560130 -- /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII' -steam\0
Game process added : AppID 560130 "/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=560130 -- /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII' -steam", ProcID 7269, IP 0.0.0.0:0
chdir "/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II"
Could not connect to X session manager: Could not open network socket
Could not connect to X session manager: Could not open network socket
Could not connect to X session manager: Could not open network socket
flock /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationSans-Italic.ttf LOCK_SH failed. errno = 13flock /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf LOCK_SH failed. errno = 13flock /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf LOCK_SH failed. errno = 13flock /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf LOCK_SH failed. errno = 13flock /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf LOCK_SH failed. errno = 13GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
GameAction [AppID 560130, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Found path: /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII
Mono path[0] = '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII_Data/Mono/etc'
Receiving unhandled NULL exception
#0  0x007fffd9225430 in mono_amd64_throw_exception
#1  0x007fffd9225470 in mono_get_trampoline_func
#2  0x007fffd9225480 in mono_print_method_from_ip
#3  0x007fffd92254d0 in std::vector<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, std::allocator<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > > >::~vector()
#4  0x007fffd9225860 in std::map<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, std::less<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > > > >::~map()
Thread (nil) may have been prematurely finalized
Game process removed: AppID 560130 "/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=560130 -- /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity II/PillarsOfEternityII' -steam", ProcID 7269 
ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 7271
ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 7270
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
```

Other game:

```
ExecuteSteamURL: "steam://open/steam://rungameid/640820"
ExecuteSteamURL: "steam://rungameid/640820"
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:./Kingmaker_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=640820 -- /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker/Kingmaker.exe'\0
Game process added : AppID 640820 "LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:./Kingmaker_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=640820 -- /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker/Kingmaker.exe'", ProcID 7297, IP 0.0.0.0:0
chdir "/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker"
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object './Kingmaker_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object './Kingmaker_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
GameAction [AppID 640820, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object './Kingmaker_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker/Kingmaker.exe: 1: MZ����@��: not found
/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker/Kingmaker.exe: 2: $?@^�[@^�[@^�[/:�ZJ^�[/:�ZE^�[/:�Z�^�[/:�ZB^�[: not found
/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker/Kingmaker.exe: 3: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
Game process removed: AppID 640820 "LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:./Kingmaker_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=640820 -- /home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/szymon-m-sabat/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Pathfinder Kingmaker/Kingmaker.exe'", ProcID 7297 
ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 7299
ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 7298
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed

(steam:6724): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
```

Comment: What brand/model system? What model nVidia? Did you purge before reinstalling driver? Otherwise you can get conflicts. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413 To see if driver installed: `dkms status`