# HELP Boot problem after moving/resizing partitions, repeatedly randomly enters Emergency Mode Ubuntu 23

Tags: boot, grub2

```
[  2.223916]
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctI -xb" to view system logs,
"systemctI reboot" to reboot,
"systemctl default" or "exit'
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default. target
1 559.079295] libvirt-guests.sh[1893]:Can't connect to default. Skipping.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalct -x" to view system logs,
"systemctI reboot" to reboot, "systemctI default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):
```

Keeps coming up somewhat randomly. Can only boot machine normally by entering maintenance mode and issuing the cmd:

```
systemctI reboot
```

Pls help, I’ve tried boot-repair as well as tux boot rescue, claims all issues fixed but problem remains.

OS etc details below-

Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 12 × AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor
Memory: 31.0 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Did you "move/resize partitions" on an active disk? Were any of the disk's partitions mounted at the time? What, exactly, did you do? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I used gparted to do all moving resizing offline.

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode? if not post link to summary report from Boot-Repair as ot siggests. If you can boot to grub menu, then not boot issue. May be video issue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413  If graphics driver installed, this should show it: `dkms status`

Comment: Thank you boot-repair summary link- https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fZNmpdJXDV/
PS boot-repair only seemd to have issues with /sdb3, which is an external backup drive. Whereas boot etc are on /sda

Comment: CLARIFICATION: This was a fully functional dual boot Win 11 + Ubuntu 23 previously. Again, its still functional , except it seemingly randomly enters Emergency Mode Ubuntu 23, as described above.