cant install nvidia driver on ubuntu 24.04 (GT820M card)
i want to install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run file for GT820M
and when i try to install it using terminal it wont build kernals. i have almost zero knowledge of terminal and how to use it. i will put the log file too.and feel free to ask for whatever else info needed
i ran the installer using -no-x-check and -no-nouveau-check and -no-cc-version-check
i even tried turning them off manually
i was getting
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
i dont know how can i post the entire log , so if anything is needed feel free to ask
EDIT: i tried installing the driver using
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
which out puts
Building initial module for 6.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-390
.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-390 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-390:
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (<= 390.157-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (>= 390.157); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25
.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-36-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-390
 nvidia-driver-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


With Ubuntu using the .run file is not recommended. You, in effect have to reinstall it with every kernel update. Install the nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. If you boot using grub's recovery mode the terminal install instructions are the same as server: Server install instructions
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation or  purge & install nvidia &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

i tried the method but cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version outputs no such file or directory and sudo ubuntu-drivers list just outputs nothing and sudo ubuntu-drivers install outputs All the available drivers are already installed.

You may try exporting cc as gcc and then executing the run file.
reference

hi, i cant find a release for ubuntu 24.04 , the lastest is 22.04 on their website

The driver doesn't seem to have support for newer kernel versions that means that you cannot use the official Nvdia driver package,as @oldfred suggest you might get a working driver packaged by ubuntu,follow these steps.Also it seem that your card supports a newer driver you might want to give that one a shot.

deer Blz , the version 430.40 doesnt support my graphics card. and following the ubuntu's official guide the command cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version returns no such file and directory and sudo ubuntu-drivers list just doesnt return anything                                          btw i have another thread on https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cant-install-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu24-04/298160/3 with logs and images

cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version is returning nothing beacause you have no driver installed for your graphics card,ubuntu-drivers list not returning anything might imply that ubuntu hasn't yet packaged a driver for your graphics card for 24.04 LTS,but i am not completely sure.I think that the only easy and viable solution for you is to downgarde to 22.04 LTS as its pretty stable and mature.24.04 LTS is not quite reliable yet.Remember the latest isn't necessarily the greatest.

ok so i have installed 22.04 running kernal 6.5 and it wont build kernal so what i did was i installed kernal v6.2.0 and when i run uname -r it returns 6.2.0-060200-generic  and when i install the driver using sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 it builds the modules for 6.2.0 kernal BUT it attempts to build a kernal for the v6.5 too which stops the instalation. is there a way to delete/stop the kernal v6.5 from working or the installer from building a module for it?

You can execute dpkg --list | grep linux-image to see all installed kernel images,the signed ones shouldn't brother you if secure boot is off.You can purge any unused kernel image by executing sudo apt purge <unused_imagename>.
